# Recursive select in function

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I was trying create recursive query but with no result. Below I introduced my problem.
Input data:

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (ID varchar2(100), NAME varchar2(100));
CREATE TABLE REL (ID varchar2(100), PARENT varchar2(100), 
CHILD varchar2(100), TYPEREL VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO NAME (ID, NAME) VALUES ('2123', 'AD1');
INSERT INTO NAME (ID, NAME) VALUES ('3133', 'AD2');
INSERT INTO NAME (ID, NAME) VALUES ('34535', 'AD3');
INSERT INTO NAME (ID, NAME) VALUES ('42345', 'AD4');
INSERT INTO NAME (ID, NAME) VALUES ('3422', 'AD5');
INSERT INTO NAME (ID, NAME) VALUES ('3414', 'AD6');


INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('313', '2123', '3133', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('422', '3422', '34535', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('233', '3414', '2123', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('111', '3422', '2123', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('341', '42345', '3422', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('464', '3422', '2123', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('908', '42345', '3133', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('625', '34535', '3414', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('783', '3414', '3133', 'X');
INSERT INTO REL (ID, PARENT, CHILD, TYPEREL) VALUES ('377', '3133', '34535', 'X');
```

I would like to create function returning cycle of relation if it appears. (for example (2121,3133,34535,3413,2121)).

I was trying this:

```
create or replace function aaa return ??? as
  ???
  x varchar2(10);
  z varchar2(10);
begin
  with xxx as(select distinct x1.parent, x1.child as child1
  from rel  x1 where  x1.parent = x1.child)
  select count(*) into x from xxx;
     while(x = 0 || z=100) {
        select *from xxx
        inner join rel on child1 = xxx.parent ; 
        z := z+1;
     }      
  return ???;
end;
/
```

Of course function aaa does not compile properly. First of all I don't know how to return cycle from this function. (as row? but I don't know how many columns will be necessary). Another problem is child1 in while loop in above code. How to join on last child (here child1) inside loop? It is possible select all columns xxx and only child column from rel table in this while loop? My aproach it's ok? Any tips what can I do for achieve the wanted result?

One more information. In my case, first cycle appear after this:

```
select distinct x1.parent, x1.child , x2.child , x3.child--, x4.child
from rel x1
inner join rel x2 on x1.child = x2.parent
inner join rel x3 on x2.child = x3.parent
--inner join rel x4 on x3.child = x4.parent
where  x1.parent = x1.child or x1.parent = x2.child
or x1.parent = x3.child; --or x1.parent = x4.child;
```

I only want pack above code in some function.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: Nope, It does not work because it's not tree structure. In table "rel" one "child" can have more that one "parent" and vice versa.

Comment: I still can't tell what you want the function to return. One cycle (any one cycle it can find)? ALL the cycles (however "all" is defined in this setting)? You mention "first" cycle, but you are not explaining what "first" means in this context. According to what ordering?

Comment: I was imprecise. "First" cycle means whichever row from result of query which is non empty. My idea was: I am joining "rel" table (Like in query at the end of my post.) as long as "select" returns sth non empty (in case of my topic after second join). Number of joins needed for appear non empty result plus one is equals the length of shortest cycle. From this non empty set of results I take only one row. Now I want do this action as one function.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments you wrote:

> In table "rel" one "child" can have more that one "parent" and vice
>   versa.

Maybe the following query will give you a starting point.

```
-- test data (from your question)
SQL> select * from rel;
ID   PARENT  CHILD  TYPEREL  
313  2123    3133   X        
422  3422    34535  X        
233  3414    2123   X        
111  3422    2123   X        
341  42345   3422   X        
464  3422    2123   X        
908  42345   3133   X        
625  34535   3414   X        
783  3414    3133   X        
377  3133    34535  X
```

Query / result:

```
SQL> select 
  2    parent
  3  , listagg( child, ',' ) within group ( order by child ) children
  4  from rel
  5  group by parent ;

PARENT  CHILDREN         
2123    3133             
3133    34535            
3414    2123,3133        
3422    2123,2123,34535  
34535   3414             
42345   3133,3422
```

Comment: Thank you for clue. Was helpfull. I solved my problem usin hierarchical queries from following site: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm. Thanks @MatBailie you had good idea - I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  My first thought was: use a hierarchical query.  However, as you replied "Nope..." to @MatBailie's suggestion, I used listagg().  Main thing is that you have solved the problem :-)